# Polymer 3 lit-element: Array Object changes not picked up by requestRender

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I have an object as below. Now when I change a property and call requestRender it won't trigger. As far as I see it, the property change is not detected. How can I achieve this?

```js
static get properties() {
  return {
    items: Object
    }
}

constructor() {
  super();
  this.items = {
    list: [{ a: 5, b: 6 },{ a: 5, b: 6 }]
  }
}

onClick() {
  this.items.list[1].a = 10; //change property
  requestRender(); //doesn't pick up the change...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lit-element requires you to manage your properties immutably, so to update that data point, something like the following will be required:

```
onClick() {
  let list = this.items.list.slice();
  let item = Object.assign({}, list[1]);
  item.a = 10;
  list[1] = item;
  this.items = {
    list: list
  };
  // will update on it's own with out a render request
}
```

The above is a very complete, but ES5(ish) answer to this problem. It's also possible to do this with more modern JS that would make this much more manageable.

```
onClick() {
  this.items.list[1].a = 10;
  this.items = {
    ...this.items
  };
  // will update on it's own with out a render request
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @shotofcode May I recommend to be more careful with your language? I let this pass as understandable venting of frustration, but I think others could feel differently.

Comment: This is true.  It may be more convenient to use a library like Immutable.js or Redux to manage immutable state, especially for larger projects.  @shotofcode that will get you closer to React's `setState` implementation.

Comment: @Westbrook I also tried your second solution but in Polymer it didn't triggered render :(

Comment: When you say "Polymer" you mean lit-element, correct? Here a repro with that working, it's super modern JS so it's not in most browsers without transpilation, but it here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/splash-year?path=index.html:20:57